# Removing numbers from strings

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp

So, I am working with a text file on which I am doing the following operations on the string

```
     def string_operations(string):

        1) lowercase
        2) remove integers from string
        3) remove symbols
        4) stemming
```

After this, I am still left with strings like:

```
  durham 28x23
```

I see the flaw in my approach but would like to know if there is a good, fast way to identify if there is a numeric value attached with the string.

So in the above example, I want the output to be

```
  durham
```

Another example:

```
 21st ammendment
```

Should give:

```
ammendment
```

So how do I deal with this stuff?

Comment: what is the output of your second example? `st ammendment`?

Comment: @Kevin: it is 21st ammendment only

Comment: So you want to allow `21st` but not `28x23`? How do you decide what numbers are allowable and which aren't?

Comment: oh.. sorry. for the confusion. the output will be ammendment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you requirement is, "remove any terms that start with a digit", you could do something like this:

```
def removeNumerics(s):
  return ' '.join([term for term in s.split() if not term[0].isdigit()])
```

This splits the string on whitespace and then joins with a space all the terms that do not start with a number.

And it works like this:

```
>>> removeNumerics('21st amendment')
'amendment'
>>> removeNumerics('durham 28x23')
'durham'
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, maybe show some explicit examples in your questions (showing both the initial string and your desired result).